# how to delete a specific document from firebase firestore in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried to delete a specific document form my firestore database

here is the rules of my firestore

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my java code is

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
    holder.tname.setText(datalist.get(position).getName());
    holder.ttype.setText(datalist.get(position).getType());
    holder.tdescription.setText(datalist.get(position).getDescription());

    holder.delet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            collectionRef.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document :task.getResult()){
                                String id = document.getId();
                                db.collection("user data")
                                    .document(id)
                                    .delete()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                           notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error!", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

In this code when i click the delete button it deletes all the document in firestore instead of deleting a specific document.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, here are some useful resources ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) & [2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) that might help.

Comment: I hope my answer has helped you. If so, I would appreciate it if you marked it as the correct one. All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are iterating through all the documents in the collection and deleting them one by one, instead of deleting the specific document that you want to delete. You need to identify the document that you want to delete and then call the delete() method on that specific document.

```
holder.delet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the ID of the document you want to delete
        String id = datalist.get(position).getId();

        db.collection("user data")
            .document(id)
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    // Remove the deleted item from the datalist
                    datalist.remove(position);
                    // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error!", e);
                }
            });
    }
});
```